# How to access "C:" from "x:\windows\system32>" if Windows is installed on laptop's M.2 ssd and no SATA disk?

Tags: m.2

Is it possible to select "C:" from "x:\windows\system32>" if the only drive of the laptop is an M.2 ssd.

I understand the M.2 ssd is PCIe SSDs which do not use the Motherboards SATA Chipset interface to communicate between the SSD and the Windows File system.

The M.2 ssd driver is either provided by the manufacturer or by the OS itself.

X:" is from WinRe. The Windows is installed on the only laptop's ssd M.2 type. Even if this is the case I wouldn't have thought I would not be able to access "C:" from the command prompt of WinRe. When I get the "x:\windows\system32>", I am unable to change directory to "C:". Tried typing "C:" or any other letter and all I get "The system cannot find the drive specified. Tried to run "diskpart", then "list volume" and get "There are no volumes". Tried to run "list disk" and I get "There are no fixed disks to show". If however log in to Win10, and start cmd, I can then see "c:" drive.

Comment: What is the X: drive in this situation? Is it the actual location where Windows is installed, or is it a bootable USB stick, or what?

Comment: X: would suggest the user is using WinRE to access their drive, so if they drive is functional, the user can indeed access the C: drive although it’s likely NOT that drive letter within WinRE